Editor is requesting for journal self citation
Recently, I submitted a paper to a journal listed in Scopus. They sent me review results, but some of the items in the review list are strange.  One asked why there are no references in the first two paragraphs while others asked for journal self-citations with at least six references. Should I directly report to the publisher (a big publisher in academia), ask for clarification from the editor, or contact others (another editor, COPE, etc.)?

Comments to the author (if any):
Reviewer #1: i. section i first two paragraphs have no citations. Same is first paragraph of section ii.
ii. at least 6 citations from previous issue of [redacted] from 2020 should be cited.
iii. For publication of papers, under Subscription Mode, we do not charge any Publication Fee, whatsoever, upto six pages. However, if the length of the paper exceeds six pages, after it is typeset by [redacted] Extra Page Charges (EPC) shall be applicable [redacted] per page (B&W) for [redacted] authors, and [redacted] per page (B&W) for [redacted] authors, to be paid by the authors to get the paper included in the specific Vol/Issue and printed in Hard Copy of the journal. Actual number of pages shall be informed to the author (s), after the paper is typeset, post acceptance, by the production team of [redacted]


Is that actually the comments from reviewer #1? If so, it's extremely unusual for them to talk about publication fees?

Yes. I suspected the editor reviewed by themselves without contacting (potential) reviewer.

"at least 6 citations from previous issues of [...] should be cited" Frankly, this is a burning red flag.

@JochenGlueck unless it was a special edition dedicated to the topic.  If this were the case, not citing them when submitting to the journal that published them might be a real omission

Neglecting the fact that it is extremely unusual for reviewers to talk about publication fees (see my comment to the question), there's still something weird about that screenshot. Note the first two points of the reviewer's comments are written in broken English & poor capitalization, while that is not the case for (iii). This suggests the author is different, and the obvious explanation is that the intended decision letter should have looked like:

Comments to author (if any)
Reviewer #1: yada yada blah blah
...
Information for authors
i. Something something
ii. Something something
iii. For publication of papers, under Subscription Mode, we do not charge any Publication Fee, whatsoever, upto [sic] six pages. However ...

The Information for authors is autogenerated, so it's written in Good English and contains all the journal's standard information. For whatever reason, the editor decided to truncate either the Information for authors or the reviewer's comments, but wound up mishmashing both of them together.
Assuming this guess is correct, now is not the time to complain to the publisher or COPE; instead, ask the editor to clarify if you got all the reviewer comments, since what you got appears to be incomplete.

It was confirmed that points 1-2 are from a reviewer; point 3 is from an editor.

@bugs if so, I'll guess that you're not dealing with a reputable journal. Reviewer has no comments except requests for references (one of which [point 2] is highly unusual too), and the editor did not separate their comments from the reviewer's.

A reputable journal would never ask an author to add “at least 6 citations” to papers from the same journal. Making such a request is an unethical practice that smacks of the sort of thing a predatory journal would do to improve its (probably dismal) ranking.
I don’t know what you should do, as this would depend on many details specific to your particular situation. But in general, if you want to be viewed as a serious academic you should publish your work only in serious, reputable journals.
